# My grub bootloader appears to be severely broken, how can I repair it?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Machine is currently running, I have not attempted to restart.

After running `sudo apt upgrade`, I see in the output:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-bin (2.04-1ubuntu44) ...
Setting up grub2-common (2.02-2ubuntu8.23) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:18.04.44) ...
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu44) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory.
Failed: grub-install --target=x86_64-efi  
WARNING: Bootloader is not properly installed, system may not be bootable
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-142-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-142-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-141-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-141-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-136-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-136-generic
done
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.167~18.04.1+2.04-1ubuntu44) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Which suggests there is a problem. I run `grub-emu`, and see this output:

```
error: sparse file not allowed.
error: no such device: 21b294f1-25bd-4265-9c4e-d6e4aeb57e97.
error: can't find command `linux'.
error: can't find command `initrd'.
```

Whatever option I select in `grub-emu`, I get the same results.

If I run `file -s /dev/sda`, I see:

```
/dev/sda: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=6e1fd477-4aec-4323-83b8-55c419ce471f (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
```

What do I need to do to repair this server?

---

Edit:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
LABEL=UEFI  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0 0
```

I realised I was mistaken, `/dev/sda` is NOT my boot drive, `/dev/vda` is (this is a digitalocean vm):

```
$ file -s /dev/vda
/dev/vda: DOS/MBR boot sector, extended partition table (last)
```

```
$ lsblk -o +PARTUUID /dev/vda
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT PARTUUID
vda     252:0    0   50G  0 disk            
├─vda1  252:1    0 49.9G  0 part /          bcf3ccb8-bce6-4498-93fb-1b9bd59fc81c
├─vda14 252:14   0    4M  0 part            2081abbc-a4ba-496a-b391-07952095f65d
└─vda15 252:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi  ee783a1a-c5d0-42d9-b874-71796971f49b
```

```
$ bootctl --path /boot/efi status
File system "/boot/efi" has wrong type for an EFI System Partition (ESP).
System:
    Not booted with EFI

Boot Loader Binaries:
          ESP: /boot/efi
systemd-boot not installed in ESP.
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

Default Boot Entry:
Failed to open "/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf": No such file or directory
Failed to read boot config from "/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf": No such file or directory
Failed to load bootspec config from "/boot/efi/loader": No such file or directory
```

```
$ sudo tree -p /boot/efi
/boot/efi
├── [drwxr-xr-x]  EFI
│   ├── [drwxr-xr-x]  BOOT
│   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  BOOTX64.CSV
│   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  BOOTX64.EFI
│   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  fbx64.efi
│   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  grub.cfg
│   │   ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  grubx64.efi
│   │   └── [-rwxr-xr-x]  mmx64.efi
│   └── [drwxr-xr-x]  ubuntu
│       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  BOOTX64.CSV
│       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  grub.cfg
│       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  grubx64.efi
│       ├── [-rwxr-xr-x]  mmx64.efi
│       └── [-rwxr-xr-x]  shimx64.efi
└── [drwxr-xr-x]  boot
    └── [drwxr-xr-x]  grub
        └── [-rwxr-xr-x]  grub.cfg
```

Comment: If UEFI system check fstab mount of ESP, UEFI entry & files in ESP. `cat /etc/fstab` should have UUID of ESP. `sudo efibootmgr -v` should have guid/partUUID of ESP. To see UUID/partUUID. `lsblk -o +PARTUUID /dev/sda`  & `sudo tree -p /boot/efi` to see UEFI boot files.  And maybe `sudo bootctl --path /boot/efi status`

Comment: @oldfred thanks for your reply, I added the requested outputs - looks like there is a serious problem, but I'm not sure how to proceed!

Comment: I do not know VMs. It looks like you are mounting with labels, so need to confirm they are correct. This shows labels `lsblk -f` Looks like standard set of UEFI boot files in ESP. What does `sudo efibootmgr -v` show? Is ESP not FAT32? 'sudo parted -l`

Comment: `efibootmgr -v`: "EFI variables are not supported on this system."

Comment: This is a DigitalOcean VM - it shouldn't be configured to use EFI.

Comment: Are you booted in BIOS mode, then efibootmgr does not work. You show ESP with UEFI boot files, so it looks like system does support UEFI. How you boot install/repair media is then how it installs or repairs. So if really UEFI, always boot in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Journal recovery is generally performed automatically when required at the time of mounting the filesystem. If you would like to do it manually, you can ensure the file system is *not* mounted, then [run `e2fsck`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/e2fsck.8.html).

Comment: In which case, would we normally expect this problem to disappear (self-repair) on boot?

Comment: Seems this was a red herring - `/dev/sda` has unrelated (!) journal issues.